# Lodash in Angular2+/Typescript -- groupBy getting cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature when trying to pass parameter?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, underscore.js, lodash

Stackblitz here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qbpnqc

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import _ from "lodash";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  array: [
    {
        "BookingId": 0,
        "OrderNumber": "331049910611",
        "ArrivalTime": "07:00:00",
        "DepartureTime": "14:00:00",
        "Duration": "07:00:00",
    },
    {
        "BookingId": 0,
        "OrderNumber": "331049910611",
        "ArrivalTime": "07:00:00",
        "DepartureTime": "14:00:00",
        "Duration": "07:00:00",
    },
    {
        "BookingId": 0,
        "OrderNumber": "331049910611",
        "ArrivalTime": "07:00:00",
        "DepartureTime": "14:00:00",
        "Duration": "07:00:00",

    },
    {
        "BookingId": 0,
        "OrderNumber": "331049910611",
        "ArrivalTime": "07:00:00",
        "DepartureTime": "14:00:00",
        "Duration": "07:00:00",


    },
    {
        "BookingId": 0,
        "OrderNumber": "331049910611",
        "ArrivalTime": "07:00:00",
        "DepartureTime": "14:00:00",
        "Duration": "07:00:00",


    },
    {
        "BookingId": 0,
        "OrderNumber": "331049910611",
        "ArrivalTime": "07:00:00",
        "DepartureTime": "14:00:00",
        "Duration": "07:00:00",

        "DeliveryStatus": "Accepted"
    },
    {
        "BookingId": 59088,
        "OrderNumber": "691",
        "ArrivalTime": "11:00:00",
        "DepartureTime": "12:00:00",
        "Duration": "01:00:00",

        "DeliveryStatus": "Accepted"
    }
];

countSmth: any;

ngOnInit() {

  // not working
  console.log( _(this.array).groupBy('DeliveryStatus').values().map(
      (group) => ({ ...group[0], qty: group.length }).value()
    ));
}



}
```

Comment: I don't know what's going on in Stackblitz; when I export the project, run `npm install` and load it up in VS Code on my machine, I get no error.

Comment: can you provide your typings.json file @SebastianG

Comment: @MattMcCutchen does the object display/get built correctly in the console as well?

Comment: @VaibhavKumarGoyal I can't find any such file in my project. A global search with 'everything' software on my computer reveleas only some files called typings.json inside various node_modules from other projects.

Comment: @SebastianG I know TypeScript but I'm not familiar with how to run Angular projects.  I tried `ng serve` but got an error, `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'REDACTED/src/main.ts' in 'REDACTED/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs'`.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen I think the stackblitz is messed up for some odd reason. I have just created a blank component for my application and copied only the stackblitz code. No errors and it seems to work but on the console I'm now getting 'undefined'.

Comment: Looks like you may be missing a `return` before `_(param)` (or alternatively, remove the curly braces).

Comment: @MattMcCutchen ah that might be it -- I have since modified the function to just console.log the whole thing which has made it unnecessary to add the return. I'm no longer getting undefined but now I'm getting an empty array, literally just the brackets.

Comment: If the definition of `array` is still as in the StackBlitz, `array: [ { "BookingId": 0 ... } ]`, then you are declaring a really complicated type for the `array` but not initializing it and it remains `undefined`.  Try replacing `array:` with `array =`.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen that.... worked O.o wow. Now the only problem that I'm having is that the new objects have all data inside them as well, not just the key that I'm interested. If you have suggestions on how to map as keys just the values of the keys that I'm filtering it would be great. Also if you want to post as an answer I'll be glad to mark it as the solution! Thanks!

Comment: Replacing `...group[0]` with `DeliveryStatus: group[0].DeliveryStatus` should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `array` is being declared with a very complicated type (following the colon) but not actually initialized, so it is `undefined`.  Replace `array:` with `array =`.